# What would be the best approach to temporarily save a big query result(~100k rows) in S3?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm having a lambda do a query in mysql then save that query result to S3,where it will be used by another lambda to do something else with all that data.

Im running out of lambda memory since the query result is too big and is being saved to a variable before being sent to S3.

You guys have any idea of how can I approach this?

Comment: Could you add more memory to the lambda? Or have you maxed out the MB? Also could you show us your currently solution? IS the data preloaded into a value? Can you break the data up into smaller bits?

Comment: Yeah the memory is maxed out.
And yeah currently its being saved to a variable before being saved to S3.
The lambda is running for around 15 seconds before failing cause of max memory.


My next approach is trying to stream the query data to S3 instead of trying to send it as whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in the [Lambda Limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) resource the max memory is 3,008 MB and the max directory storage a Lambda can use is 512 MB.

While I do not know your exact use case, this is an example of streaming data in a memory efficient way, using python: [Memory-efficient large dataset streaming to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47596051/5787099)

In my experience it is better to use tools designed around data extraction/loading for rds to s3 than building tooling in Lambda. For example, you could use [Data Pipeline to Export MySQL Data to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-mysql.html). Data pipeline can be configured with ec2 instances to handler larger data sets. Much larger and more efficent than a Lambda handler.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into Data Pipeline and it seems like its the best approach. I'm gonna have to take a deeper look and find a way to implement it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data you're sending to s3 in CSV or JSON format? Cause if it is you can use this s3 feature called [s3 select](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-s3-announces-new-features-for-s3-select/) which would query that object for you given some sql syntax and save memory in your Lambda. Would this work for the use case? Here is a blog post where they show how to do this: 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/

HTH

-James